# ENS Resolver Transaction

Tags: transactions, ens

If I want to find out which address a name resolves to, say example.eth, does this mean I need to send a transaction to the appropriate ENS contract for resolution?
Does running a local node reduce this to a call, thereby eliminating gas cost?
Are there any cached resources for lookups and resolutions?

Comment: Check out the linked question for information on a call vs a transaction. Resolving a name only requires a call.

Comment: I understand the difference between a transaction and a call. My question is in relation to caching the results and the options available for resolution.

Comment: If you only want to know the status of an address the you have to make a call and that should be free.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand the question.
If you want to resolve a name you just have to call the resolver() method is the ens smart contract,passing it the namehash of the domain name,then if a resolver exist for that namehash just call the addr() of the designated resolver again passing the namehash.You are right in that since it's just a call and not a tx there is no associated gas cost.
i'm not aware of any other way to do it,afaik there aren't any cached services/lookup tables where you can get the corresponding address without interacting wit the ens contract.

http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/implementers.html#resolving-names

You can also see all the steps needed by using https://mycrypto.com/contracts/interact
then inputing the contract address for the ens: 0x314159265dD8dbb310642f98f50C066173C1259b
copy the ABI and call the resolver function.

If you are looking for online resources to determine what address an ens domain resolves to you can use
https://www.etherchain.org/ens/lookup
https://etherscan.io/enslookup